# How to correlate date in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a scenario in jmeter as follows:

Jmeter script contains flight booking as first user books ticket. If **first** user books on **1-January-2017** then the **second** user must books on **2-January-2017** and the next user follows same pattern.

My query is how to implement the above scenario using jmeter.

Comment: can you share the structure of your test plan?

Comment: 1st user:departure date-22/5/2017 , arrival date-25/5/2017    2nd user:departure date-23/5/2017 , arrival date- 26/5/2017 and soon.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter under your thread group **start at 0** and **increment 1** **Reference name Counter**

Then add a beanshell pre processor under the request and add the following code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

int Counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Counter"));

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy"); 

if(Counter == 0){
Date date1 = sdf.parse(vars.get("DepDATE1"));// DepDATE1 = Jmeter variable that holds the first departure date
Date date2 = sdf.parse(vars.get("ArrDATE1"));// ArrDATE1 = Jmeter variable that holds the first arrival date


Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(date1);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
date1 = cal.getTime();
props.put(("NextDep"), sdf.format(date1));

cal.setTime(date2);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
date2 = cal.getTime();
props.put(("NextArr"), sdf.format(date2));
}

if(Counter > 0){
datex = sdf.parse(props.get("NextDep"));
datey = sdf.parse(props.get("NextArr"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(datex);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
datex = cal.getTime();
props.put(("NextDep"), sdf.format(datex));

cal.setTime(datey);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
datey = cal.getTime();
props.put(("NextArr"), sdf.format(datey));

}
```

Now you use ${__P(NextDep)} instead of the variable which holds the departure date and ${__P(NextArr)} instead of the variable that holds the arrival date.

I think you could make it smaller, but it does the idea.

Hope it helps.